# Post id to multiple targets and load content from multiple targets using jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post id to multiple targets with ajax, it works mostly.

Example : `<li class="nav_link" id="5">test</li>`

I created two post method in one function, sometimes it loads late.
And is there a way to post id to targets and load content on page load ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 function load_page_details(id){
  $.ajax({
   url:"modules/colons.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{id:id},
   success:function(data){
    $('#colons').html(data);
   }
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"modules/card.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{id:id},
   success:function(data){
    $('#cards').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 load_page_details(1);
 $('a[class="nav-link catchTab"]').click(function(){
  var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
  load_page_details(page_id);
 });
});
```

Comment: *"It works mostly"*  ... doesn't identify a specific problem and what does *"it loads late"* mean in more technical terms?

Comment: Queue the ajaxing. Send the second ajax in the success of the first. Alternatively make ONE call and return colons and cards in one reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue the ajaxing. Send the second ajax in the success of the first. Alternatively make ONE call and return colons and cards in one reply

Assuming the `a[class="nav-link catchTab"]` is static - if not you need to delegate from nearest static container

```js
const load_page_details = function(id) {
  console.log("ajaxing", id)
  $.ajax({
    url: "modules/colons.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#colons').html(data);
      $.ajax({
        url: "modules/card.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          id: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#cards').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}


$(function() {
  $('a.nav-link').on("click", function() {
    var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
    load_page_details(page_id);
  }).eq(0).click(); // initialise
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="nav-link" id="1">Link 1</a> | <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="2">Link 2</a> | <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="3">Link 1</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I add **.eq(0).click();** it doesnt load content. just a blank page.

Comment: I do not have your HTML to see why to do. Show your HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: html :) its to long and there is nothing to do with html part, its because of this **eq(0)** causing problem. its set 1 in my function. 1 loads random contents on page load but 0 loads nothing because there is no content with id 0. is there a way to get id of active tab on page load ?

Comment: eq(0) is the first link.

Comment: but it doesnt get the first one, it gets random id in 10 ids.

Comment: Nope. Show me please

Comment: my mistake sorry its because of my if else in php part. thank you so much.